# How to get the size of the "Delete" button in a UITableViewCell when swipe to delete?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I add a datetime label on the right of a table cell. When swip-to-delete shows the "Delete" button, the datetime label need to shift left a little bit. But how to get the "Delete" button's size?

I tried to find it in the cell.subviews but failed.

Comment: Probably you don't need to know the size for your purpose, so I suggested a method in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to know the button's size. Instead, use the size of the cell's `contentView` property to calculate the sizes of the subviews. When swiping over a cell, UIKit will adapt the `contentView`'s size and call `layoutSubviews` on the cell-object. In your subclass of UITableViewCell, overwrite the `layoutSubviews` method and set the appropriate sizes to the subviews.

Look at [RecipeTableViewCell.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) of Apple's iPhoneCoreDataRecipes sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in your custom Cell class

```
 - (void)layoutSubviews {
        [super layoutSubviews];
        NSMutableArray *subviews = [self.subviews mutableCopy];
        while (subviews.count > 0)
        {
            UIView *subV = subviews[0];
            [subviews removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            if ([NSStringFromClass([subV class])isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView"]) 
           {
            UIView *deleteButtonView = (UIView *)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
            CGFloat  deleteBtnHeight=deleteButtonView.frame.size.height;//here you get the height
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The size adjusts to fit the text contained. See the following code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Dynamic width!";
}
```

vs

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"⏎";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't override layoutSubviews method in your custom table view cell than my approach is:

1. Create your custom subview, set frame basing on contentView.bounds.
2. Set `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.
3. Add your custom subview to ContentView of a cell.
4. Configure cell for [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe/3309737#3309737)

Now when you swipe on cell the delete button appears and your view auto resizes with contentView.

Answer (score -1):

The delete button is 63x33.

Comment: but if it's in non-english the size will change.