# How to enable swipe to delete cell in a TableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a **`UIViewController` that implements TableViews delegate and datasource** protocols.
Now I want to add "swipe to delete" gesture to cells.

How should I go about it.

I have given a blank implementation of `commitEditingStyle` method and also set the Editing property to YES.

Still the swipe feature is not coming .

Now Do I need to separately add `UISwipeGesture` to each cell ?

Or  am  I missing something ?

Comment: Refer the link, it may help you,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe

Comment: I have overridden commitEditingStyle and set Editing to YES and also NOW I have overridden CanEditRowAtIndexPath as well.

Normal Edit controls come on which on clicking delete button appears.
But not on swiping!
Is it because My class is a subclass of UIViewController and only implements the delegate and datasource methods but not of UITableViewController which might be doing something to enable a swipe gesture.

Comment: I just set up a UITableView as an IBOutlet in a UIViewController yesterday, and following exactly like that post I showed, I have swipe to delete. So I can say you don't need to enable swipe gestures, though if you really can't get it working any other way, you might have to resort to that.

Comment: btw the problem was solved, I had actually overridden editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath and it was returning None when table wasn't in editing mode and thats what the problem was.
I added that method for something I was doing previously but forgot to remove it when the requirement changed.

Comment: Swift 4 : https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2018/01/table-swipe-actions-in-swift-4-using.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You don't have to set `editing:YES` if you need to show Delete button on cell swipe. You have to implement `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` and return YES from there for rows you need to edit/delete. This is not necessary when your tableView's dataSource is a subclass of UITableViewContoller - this method, if not overridden, returns YES by default. In all other cases you have to implement it.

**EDIT:** Together we have found the problem - `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` returned `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` if table wasn't in editing mode.

Comment: Did you remove `[tableView setEditing:YES];`?

Comment: If I remove it, the basic delete button doesn't come at all !

Comment: If you don't remove it, you put your table into editing state where swipes don't work. It's either round red minus button on the left or swipes, not together.

Comment: My delete button appears when I click on that edit button on each cell on left hand side when setEditing is true but nothing happens when swipe.

Comment: For the third time - remove `setEditing:YES` **AND** implement `canEditRowAtIndexPath` to have what you need.

Comment: now I have removed setEditing statement but nothing is happening when I swipe.
Is it because I am using a UIViewController and not a TabelViewController which might be adding swipe gestures to each cell by default.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6985/discussion-between-amogh-talpallikar-and-kyr-dunenkoff)

Comment: I want to add that `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` may not be enough. You also have to implement `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: It is hiding my text when I swipe. Can we change that behaviour?

Comment: you should remove this method. 
```objc
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 61):

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39155/dan) has commented above, you need to implement the following table view delegate methods:

1. `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`
2. `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Note: I have tried this in iOS 6 and iOS 7.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return YES - we will be able to delete all rows
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Perform the real delete action here. Note: you may need to check editing style
    //   if you do not perform delete only.
    NSLog(@"Deleted row.");
}
```

Comment: I just tested this in iOS 8.1.2 on an iPhone 6 and it works. I only needed to implement the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method as editing should be YES by default.

Answer (score 25):

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Comment: Noteworthy / comment for newbies like me: the row still needs to be deleted, as well as the datasource (e.g. array) needs to be reduced.

Answer (score 12):

Please try this code in swift,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
   // let the controller to know that able to edit tableView's row 
   return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  {
   // if you want to apply with iOS 8 or earlier version you must add this function too. (just left in blank code)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?  {
   // add the action button you want to show when swiping on tableView's cell , in this case add the delete button.
   let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action , indexPath) -> Void in

   // Your delete code here.....
   .........
   .........
   })

   // You can set its properties like normal button
   deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

   return [deleteAction]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the following to your class:

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return(YES);
}
```

Comment: not working for me :(
Is it because my class is a subclass of UIViewController and I need to do something extra which UITabelViewController does ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar, How did You solve your problem? Could you post your solution? I also have the same issue. Also my class is a subclass of UIViewController, and all cells' of my tableView are subclass of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 3):

Conclusion of [Kyr Dunenkoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918233/kyr-dunenkoff) chat is

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

should not be defined if you need delete button to appear on swipe.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to populate the table view, this worked for me:

- Make sure `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath` returns true always
- In your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath` implementation, do not delete the row directly from the table view. Instead, delete it using your managed object context, e.g.:

  ```
  if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
      let word = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Word
      self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(word)
      self.saveManagedObjectContext()
  }

  func saveManagedObjectContext() {
      do {
          try self.managedObjectContext.save()
      } catch {
          let saveError = error as NSError
          print("\(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem for me too...I could only get swiping to delete to work once every 10 or so attempts.  It turns out the `gesture` on the TV was being blocked by another gesture in the parent view controller.  The TV was nested in a `MMDrawerController` (swipe able drawer layout).

Just configuring the gesture recognizer in the drawer controller to not respond to close gestures in the flanking drawers allowed swipe to delete to work in my TV.

You could also try doing something like this with the `gesture delegate`:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm having the same exact problem with MMDrawerController..  Could you elaborate on "configuring the gesture recognizer in the drawer controller to not respond to close gestures in the flanking drawers allowed swipe to delete to work in my TV".  How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is the swift version

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, seems like you must have `editing` on `UITableView` set to `NO` for swiping to work.

`self.tableView.editing = NO;`

Answer (score 0):

After iOS 8.0, you can custom you action in

```
- (nullable NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *post= [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil]; 


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [posts count];

    if (row < count) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
                    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [posts count];

    if (row < count) {

        [posts removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can see all necessary methods by creating a UITableViewController class (temporary) in XCode 5 and then copy which method you would like to use. Those methods you need will be commented out with pre-filled in lines you desire.

Comment: Well, this answer is for other people who're looking for the answer, for sure. :)