# Not able to show Delete button

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am trying to implement an alarm clock app **just like apple's Clock app**.On the click of Edit button on the left hand side I want to make **table enter into Editing mode with red circles on left side of every cell(custom UITableViewCell) And on the click of that red circle want to show "Delete" button/action on the right side.**

I have been trying a lot and went through many sites but still could not figure out. Can someone please see what mistake I am making?

I have referred below and many others links:
    [How to enable swipe to delete cell in a TableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983094/how-to-enable-swipe-to-delete-cell-in-a-tableview?lq=1)
    [UITableViewCell, show delete button on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe?lq=1&newreg=24ed6f267baf4094b425d5b74f456866)

```
class SavedAlarmListViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var alarms = [AlarmDataObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad() 
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)
refreshList()
}

func refreshList() {

alarms = AlarmsList.sharedInstance.allSavedAlarms()
tableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return alarms.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cellIdentifier = "cell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlarmTableViewCell

// custom code to set data ....

return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
return true // all cells are editable
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if editingStyle == .Delete {
let alarm = alarms.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
AlarmsList.sharedInstance.removeAnAlarm(alarm) 
}
}

}

class AlarmTableViewCell:UITableViewCell {
// IBOutlets

override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement 
`tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:)` and return `.Delete`

Comment: I implemented but it did not any difference. self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem() // on the tap of Edit button Done button appears but table does not go into editing mode.  But when I set the **@IBAction** on Edit button then red circled button appears but no event on Swipe.  I am also getting this message whenever I tried to Swipe the cell:  **MyApp[944:17497] must have a swipe to delete confirmation view when installing the swipe to delete gobbler**