# ios UITableView delete/re-arrange editing mode but not show delete icon

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have create a `UITableView` in editing mode, I force it run into editing mode on viewDidLoad function of a viewcontroller containing this tableview. Everything is fine, each row of table has a delete icon on the left, `re-arrange` icon on the right. I implemented

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
       return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     return YES;
}
```

The problem is on each row I don't want to show a red delete icon on the left, just show a re-arrange icon on the right. When user want to delete, he/she can swipe a row to delete.

The reason I want to do this is I don't encourage user to delete a row product. I understand I can put a Edit button, when user click on this button, I turn into Edit mode, but I don't want to do so, I want to display a re-arrange function on the beginning when user go into my viewcontroller.

Can I do so.

Let me put some screen shot

[image: This is what I got]

[image: This is what I want to show. When user swipe I want to show a Delete button overlay the arrange icon on the right]

The first image is what I got.

The second image is what I actually want to show. When user swipe I want to show a Delete button overlay the arrange icon on the right

Comment: Can you add some screen shot?

Comment: try to change the editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath to be UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone?

Comment: @verbumdei Thks, I tried this but user can't swipe to delete, nothing happen when user swipe

Comment: @Khawar Thks, let me take some screen shots. :)

Comment: It might not be possible to hide the delete icon but still enabling the delete when the table is in editing mode. But you can still enable the swipe to delete when the table view is not in editing mode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @verbumdei. :) I consider to try.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think you can use swipe to delete when the tableview is in edit mode, instead you can add `UISwipeGesture` and implement your own custom button.

If you are doing with gestures then you need to implement following delegate methods of `UITableView`.

Setting the editing style to none:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone; 
}
```

This tells that the rows should not be indented while the table view is in editing mode

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

You can refer [this](http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/swipe-gestures-on-uitableview) link to know how to add swipe gesture to `UITableView`.

Comment: Thanks, I've think about customize gesture recognizer for uitableview. I just don't know is there any built-in property of table allows me to do that simply. :) Maybe I must do this for my requirement