# how to delete a row in UITableView in Xcode 6.2?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I wanna delete a particular row while I drag it. 
Here is part of code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and make the code be formatted as code either by adding four spaces before every line or using the {} button

Comment: reload the table after removing cell

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView reloadData];
   }

}
```

Comment: what happening, can define in brief?

Comment: der is no error in the code, but things doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added the code but the thing is rows are not deleting and hence no change.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return tableData.count;
}

Answer (score 0):

Do you set delegate ?

```c
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

With corresponding [How do I get the delete button to show when swiping on a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe)

```c
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // delete from model
        // [self.tableView reloadData]
    }    
}
```

You can put on breakpoints into your code for check call functions

Answer (score 0):

yagnesh dobariya's answer is a working solution, and I would like to propose a modification that makes it more efficient.

Since you are only deleting one row at a time, you can keep using `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` as in your original code.  Just sandwich it between `-beginUpdates` and `-endUpdates`.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         [tableView beginUpdates];

         [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

         [tableView endUpdates];
   }

}
```