# Custom footer view with gesture and button

Tags: ios, swift

I want a create a special footer in my View.

Who would look something like that. [image]

So you would have to swipe right on the footer, to make appears the two button instead.
To have the same effect as when you swipe right on a cell for exemple in the Mail app.

My question is what would be the best way to create this special footer ? And how ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a lot of ways, i will show you a very basic one.

You do your view, with the two containers. In the first container you got the "Swipe right" label in a view, and underneath it there is the "Finish" and "Delete" container set up. Than you hide the "finish" and "delete" container view (hidden = true).

On the top container view you add a swipe gesture, and when that gets fired, you hide (hidden = true) the top container "Swipe right" view, and show (hidden = false) the bottom container.

Comment: The fact that it could be done in a lot of ways, is why i'm asking the question. What would be the best way of doing that? Even if what you just answered seems a very valid way of doing it

Comment: It is a valid way to do it, but you can always customize a solution for your needs. What would be the best? maybe more info would help, but i think the above solution is pretty solid.

Comment: I'm gonna try it i'll let you know

Comment: The best would be more than a swipe, it's a dragging gesture like the one on a cell in the Mail app, so i'm not really sure your technique with containers really works with what i want to do. What do you think ?

Comment: well, i do not know for sure what do you mean under the "one on a cell in the Mail app". 
There is built in native control, which allows you to do something like you want. take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe

But this is for UITableViewCell, and this is not for presenting multiple options, it present only a delete button, while the cells content remains partly visible.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the effect i want, but with two options and without a part, partly visible

Comment: i would rethink on what you need. Using a control like this will provide for pretty bad UX. And bad UX will result confused users, what will result bad ratings.

Comment: You really think it's bad UX? Sounds easy to understand for an user. You swipe/drag a big button, who reveals underneath two different buttons with two different actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92162/discussion-between-luis-and-dirtydanee).