# Flipping over UITableViewRowAnimationLeft animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am using `UITableViewRowAnimationLeft` animation for deleting a cell in my tableView.

My problem is just I want to flip the animation over - the animation is taking all the cells below the deleted cell and moving them up, I need the opposite, I want the animation to take all the cells **above** the deleted cell and moving them down.

Anyone knows how can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you need a animation for deleting cells with a swipe gesture that is already integrated . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe

Comment: @Mingebag I don't use this swipe gesture, I use my own (when the user swipes the cell for over half of the screen the cell is being deleted, without a "Delete" button). Any idea how can I get this animation?