# Delete button shows in table view cell before user swipes to delete

Tags: ios, tableview

I added swipe to delete optionality to a table view cell by implementing

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Perform the real delete action here. Note: you may need to check editing style
    //   if you do not perform delete only.
    NSLog(@"Deleted row.");
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

This is resulting in my table loading in such a way that a delete button is immediately displayed on the left. I only want a swipe to delete option, I don't want any delete button showing when the table first loads. What do I need to change?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3309737/192976

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell, show delete button on swipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second function (editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath), and change the first one to the one below:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            //add code here for when you hit delete
        }    
    }
```