# UITableView edit mode not showing delete button

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm replicating the sample Food Tracker app from apple and have an issue where the items from my TableView in Edit mode don't show the left hand delete icon (the round red one).  If I swipe left I get a delete button on the right.  I've downloaded the Food Tracker code and it works.

The difference I can see is that the sample app has implemented a UITableViewController, whereas I have a UITableView within a standard UIViewController.  I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

There are some similar questions but they are older versions of Swift / Ios, so I'm not sure they are still relevant.

Here is the link to the sample app https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1

Here are the funcs I recently added that should make it work

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
    //delete the row from the dataSource
        dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    }
    else if editingStyle == .insert {
    //create a new instance and insert the row

    }

}
```

And I added this to the ViewDidLoad() to get the Edit button in the Nav bar

```
 navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
```

Here's what the Food Tracker example looks like;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FwV3.png)

and mine is missing the left hand button.  The only difference I can see is that I'm using a TableView inside a ViewController.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: share some code

Comment: Without seeing your entire setup this is hard to diagnose.  Possibly this will shine some light:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe

Comment: Add the action method of editButtonItem

Comment: Nirav D - can you explain more about what action method needs to get added and how?

Comment: @NickS You have set editButtonItem at leftBarButtonItem, then show the action method of editButtonItem the method that will call when you press this edit button

Comment: @AgnosticDev Thanks.  That looks like an IOS8 example, it doesn't have the left hand side round delete thingo.

Comment: @NIravD thanks.  Not sure I quite understand - the sample app doesn't seem to do that.  The method called when pressing the edit button seems to be 'built in'?

Comment: What is editButtonItem here ? You have bind some action method with don't you having it?

Answer (score 2):

No need to check the title of the barButtonItem as tapping it already toggles its state and passes the correct state in editing param.

Also, when overriding, you need to invoke super's implementation as absence would always show the delete indicator.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this.  Effectively there's a fair bit of 'magic' that a UITableViewController is doing.  To recreate this in a normal UIViewController with a TableView you have to override the SetEditing function and based on the title of the button put it in edit mode.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {


    let status = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title



    if status == "Edit" {

        tableView.isEditing = true

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "Done"

        }

    else {

        tableView.isEditing = false

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit"

    }

}
```