# UITableView Force Right-to-Left swipe to delete not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have uiviewcontroller with uitableview

and swipe to delete work fine but

when I set uitableview semantic to force right-to-left the swipe to delete not even shown in the tableview

[image]

Comment: Below link may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309737/5184217

Comment: implement `canEditRowAt` and set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing`  as false.

Answer (score 0):

```
 classViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var yourArray : [Type] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tablView.delegate = self
        tablView.dataSource = self
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return yourArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
           return true
    }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      if editingStyle == .delete{
         tableView.beginUpdates()
               yourArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                  tableView.endUpdates()
                  tableView.reloadData()
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Add UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource required method to your view controller class and in your viewDidLoad() method Write tablView.delegate = self, tablView.dataSource = self

Comment: Do not explain it here. Explain it in the answer. Edit your answer.