# How to delete tableviewcell with the help of pan gesture?

Tags: ios

I want to drag the cell out of screen in left direction to delete it. I don't want to show the delete option of table view edit mode. Showing delete option is very old and traditional method thats why I want to do this with the help of gestures.

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell, show delete button on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to you program:

```
let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("handlePan")))
recognizer.delegate = self
addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

And then make method to use this recognizer:

```
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
     if recognizer.state == .began {
        originalCenter = center
     }
     if recognizer.state == .changed {
        let transition = recognizer.translation(in: self)
        center = CGPoint(x: originalCenter.x + transition.x, y: originalCenter.y)
        deleteOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0
     }
     if recognizer.state == .ended {
        let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
        if !deleteOnDragRelease {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
        }
        if deleteOnDragRelease {
            if delegate != nil && toDoItem != nil {
               delegate!.toDoItemDeleted(todoitem: toDoItem!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i think you can get all your answers for this doubt on the link given below:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1

Comment: Thanks @Vivek Tyagi  for your link. It solved my query completely.

Comment: @AXY You are most welcome my friend

Comment: Hi AXY, their is second part also in it it can give you full picture of gesture on tableview cell