# iOS on Silicon Macs – type of M-chip matters where it shouldn't

Tags: uitableview, printing, apple-silicon

As a developer with more than a dozen iOS apps on the App Store (going back to 2011), I'm faced with a weird problem.

When testing compatibily of my apps with **Apple Silicon Macs**, I noticed that **printing** wouldn't work. On my **MacBook Air M2**, the *printer interaction controller* never appears, the app seemingly frozen. However, user input like pressing a button still gets processed. I tried to execute the printer interaction controller in a separate thread, to no avail.

BUT... Moving the unmodified source code to an **iMac M3**, then recompiling and running it, showed something completely different: perfect printing!

How can that happen? Why would the chip in the Mac make a difference?

Unfortunately, that's not all. On the flipside, I noticed that **table cells** on the M3 Mac don't show the **delete button** anymore on swiping left. The gesture works perfectly on the M2 Mac.

On order to eliminate other possible causes in my UITableViewController, I downloaded the simple table demo app here: [UITableViewCell, show delete button on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe) . It works perfectly on the M2 Mac. On the M3: no delete button.

Any suggestions? Is there a way to detect the model of the chip running inside the Mac, so that the program can execute a workaround?

*For reference: both Macs run macOS Sonoma 14.1.2, Xcode 15.0.1.*

Comment: Are you sure it's the runtime environment and not the build environment that makes a difference? If you build on M3 and move the binary to M2, does that give the same result as building on M2 and running it there?

Comment: There's an even better test: if I download the app from the App Store (in this case "RPN-97 Pro"), it will hang when attempting to print on an M2 Mac. Confirmed with an overseas customer. But it will print perfectly on a brand-new iMac M3.

Comment: Can you post the minimal amount of code needed to compile and run in order to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I've solved the delete button issue. Turns out that on the M3 Mac "Touch Alternatives" were set to "Off". My apps will now set them to "On" by default. Still looking for some simple printing code to check out why the iOS Print Panel doesn't appear on the M2 Mac, but works perfectly on the M3 Mac.